# Android - how to set margin relative to another control?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm really new to android and would appreciate any help from you.
I have a screen with different templates for two kind of products. Each template is a separate xml file where I place a bunch of controls. Every control has it's own exact place in the screen which I define with margins.
The problem is I don't know how long is going to be a text in the upper TextView. If there is a one line everything looks fine, but a few lines destroy it. 
Is there any way to stretch upper textview and at the same time keep all the rest controls relative to this textview?
The code is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/regBackground"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/regBackground" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtProductNameScreenD"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/empty"
            android:textColor="@color/_black"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:lines="1"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:singleLine="true" >
        </TextView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgProductBcgD"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="263dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:src="@drawable/frame_product_screen" >
        </ImageView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgProductScreenD"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="260dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
            android:background="@color/_white" >
        </ImageView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgProductScreendiscD"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top|center"
            android:layout_marginTop="205dp"
            android:src="@drawable/discount_bkg_product_screen" >
        </ImageView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtProdScreenPrice"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right|top"
            android:layout_marginRight="45dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="220dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:lines="1"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="@string/empty"
            android:textColor="@color/_black"
            android:textSize="18sp" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtPriceShekelD1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right|top"
            android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="230dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:lines="1"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="@string/shekel_symbol"
            android:textColor="@color/_gray"
            android:textSize="10sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtBeforeDiscD"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right|top"
            android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="237dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:lines="1"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="@string/before_discount"
            android:textColor="@color/_gray"
            android:textSize="10sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtProdScreenDiscount"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right|top"
            android:layout_marginRight="140dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="220dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:lines="1"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="@string/empty"
            android:textColor="@color/_orange"
            android:textSize="18sp" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtDiscountD"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right|top"
            android:layout_marginRight="145dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="237dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:lines="1"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="@string/bonus"
            android:textColor="@color/_gray"
            android:textSize="10sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtProdScreenDiscountPrice"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left|top"
            android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="220dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:lines="1"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="@string/empty"
            android:textColor="@color/_black"
            android:textSize="18sp" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtPriceShekelD2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left|top"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="230dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:lines="1"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="@string/shekel_symbol"
            android:textColor="@color/_gray"
            android:textSize="10sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtAfterDiscD"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left|top"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="237dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:lines="1"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="@string/after_discount"
            android:textColor="@color/_gray"
            android:textSize="10sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnShareFacebookD"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="255dp"
            android:background="@drawable/facebook_button_product_screen" >
        </Button>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtDatePSDiscD"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginRight="90dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="315dp"
            android:text="@string/exp_date"
            android:textColor="@color/_gray"
            android:textSize="14sp" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtDateProductScreenD"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="315dp"
            android:text="@string/empty"
            android:textColor="@color/_blue"
            android:textSize="14sp" >
        </TextView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgSeparatorProductScreenD"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="345dp"
            android:src="@drawable/separator_product_screen" >
        </ImageView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtDescriptionProductScreenD"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="355dp"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:text="@string/empty"
            android:textColor="@color/_black"
            android:textSize="12sp" >
        </TextView>
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Do you think you could post a mock up of what you want the output to look like? (you could use free software like GIMP, or maybe Inkscape with an Android Template pack to put something together.)

Comment: Why don't u use RelativeLayout for this?

Comment: Thanks, I checked RelativeLayout, it works fine!

Answer (score 0):

I can constrain the text to be just single line with the following parameter

```
android:singleLine = "true"
```

Moreover, you can fade the edge of it, just to make it look better

```
android:fadeScrollbars = "true"
```

If you want the users to be able to read the whole text you can add a scrolling effect.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html